# How to run RCP 4.x application under Eclipse debugger?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have created simple nearly empty Eclipse 4 application, which `XMI` looks approximately following way:

[image]

If I `export` this project as `Plug-in Development -> Eclipse Product` and run `eclipse.exe` from inside destination directory, I get two empty windows:

[image]

Which looks like as expected.

Now how to run the same from under Eclipse debugger? If I select `Debug As -> Eclipse Application` I get some separate eclipse running with some panels, and even I am able to create Hello World java project under it and run it.

Where are my two windows?

And how to get rid of all excess stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Debug Configuration` for your application set the `Program to Run` to `Run a product` and select your product id.